# Java plugin crash on Ubuntu 16.04 / Firefox ESR 52.2.0

Tags: ubuntu, java, firefox, plugin

After patching Ubuntu and Firefox ESR today (2017/6/21) the Java Plugin suddenly started to crash.

[image]

```
###!!! [Parent][MessageChannel::Call] Error: Channel error: cannot send/recv
```

I have tried to empty the browser and Java Plugin caches.

I have also tried to enable the plugin console and logging but nothing indicating a crash is logged to `~/.java/deployment/log`

Comment: This seems to be the second question about this subject this week: Java plugin crashes after Firefox upgrade(this one is the other - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/372260/java-plugin-crashes-on-firefox-53). I suspect you guys will have to open a bug on Mozilla's bugzilla.

Comment: I have registered a support question on the Mozilla Support Forum.

Answer (score 1):

I have this problem too and I found a workaround. The bug is related to newest Linux kernel (I have this bug on 4.8.0-56-generic kernel on Ubuntu MATE). After booting the system using 4.8.0-54-generic kernel, Java plugin stopped crashing. Glad I didn't used apt-get autoremove this time to remove older kernel :).

Comment: That solved the problem. Thanks!

It is a confirmed bug, or something that is changed? Given the limited use of Java plugin these days I guess testing changes against it is limited.

Comment: As Java is turning into a dead tecnology for browsers(plugin/client site) so, i also doubt someone will pay attention on solving ths issue.

Comment: Yes, I am afraid so. The sole reason for my concern with this as is a VPN vendor slow moving away from applets.

Comment: It seems like Eclipse and some other applications are effected so maybe a fix will be on it's way [Eclipse Crashes with Linux Kernel 4.4.0-81-generic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/927746/eclipse-crashes-with-linux-kernel-4-4-0-81-generic)